# Odo a CSV file into PostgreSQL database

Tags: python, database, postgresql, csv, odo

I am new to PostgreSQL and `odo`. I've created the following: (I am working on Ubuntu).

I've created *superuser* `testuser` and with this user (role) I've created postgresql database `testuser` (by running `psql` and then CREATE DATABASE testuser;). In this database is a table called `testtable`. I have no troubles inserting into this database with `psycopg2`. But I've come across the `odo` module for python. Since my goal is to load `some_file.csv` into the postgresql database I thought I would use it. The usage seemed rather straightforward

```
import odo
odo.odo('some_file.csv', 'postgresql://testuser:<password>@127.0.0.1:5432/testuser::testtable')
```

But it does not work, and I get

```
NotImplementedError: Unable to parse uri to data resource: postgresql://testuser:<password>@localhost:5432/testuser
```

**Note:** instead `<password>` I have the testuser's password.

Maybe it is *obvious* and I have to implement it.. (as in the last paragraph [here](http://odo.pydata.org/en/latest/uri.html)), but I thought postgresql is supported (because postgresql is mentioned few times there, with examples).
I've tried to look [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-connect.html) under Connection URIs, but could not find a mistake. And [here](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/odo/latest/odo.pdf) is odo documentation.

Comment: Are you trying to insert a CSV file as a  single data blob or into a structured table (or multiple tables). Do you understand the basics of RDBMS, do you know the table structure? Do you know the structure of your CSV data (if any)?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to insert it in a _single_ step into single table(at least start at that, as I assume that's the basic step). I read somewhere, that `odo` uses COPY command for that. I've created the table, e.g like this
"CREATE TABLE testtable(id serial PRIMARY KEY, age integer, name varchar);" and the testing csv looks like this "25, John\n34, Petr",`\n` represents new line.

Answer (score 2):

I have used `odo` to insert a csv file into postgresql, so it is supported.  Your connection URI and code are essentially the same as mine.  Do you have the [`sqlalchemy`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) package installed?  I believe `odo` uses both `sqlalchemy` and `psycopg2` in the background.  I was able to replicate your error on a system without `sqlalchemy` installed, and installing `sqlalchemy` got me past the error.

Comment: That might really be it. I did not install sqlalchemy.. I thought I would get the _standard_ import missing error. I'll try that! Thanks

Comment: I found a similar [issue](https://github.com/blaze/odo/issues/279) on github with the same resolution.  It's not specifically related to postgres, but I imagine that the underlying code traces back to the same source for most databases that are implemented.

Comment: Ok, thanks. By the way, don't you know, whether conversion from xls->csv works? I don't have it in front of me, but I think i got similar error with `odo('<abs_path_to_my.xls>', 'my.csv')`. I feel dumb, since odo seems really easy to use, or is it _too good to be true_?

Comment: I get a similar `NotImplementedError` trying to convert an xls file, but according to [github](https://github.com/blaze/odo/issues/210) it's actually not implemented in this case, as opposed to just being due to missing packages.